# Excel VBA - Month in "mmmm" format

Tags: vba, date, excel, format

I need to use the current and the previous month in "mmmm" format, and the best solution I found is `MonthName(Month(Date))`.

However, Excel keeps giving me:

> Compile Error: Object Required

And it's driving me crazy. I'm pretty new to VBA so can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
Sub test()
    Dim CurrentMonth As Variant
    Dim PreviousMonth As Variant
    Set CurrentMonth = MonthName(Month(SetupSheet.Range("C9"))) '<-------HERE
    Set PreviousMonth = MonthName(Month(SetupSheet.Range("C9") - 1))
    ...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `Set`. You only use that if you are passing `Object` to a variable.
This line returns a `String` and not an `Object` (e.g. Range, Worksheet, Chart, etc.)

```
MonthName(Month(SetupSheet.Range("C9")))  'if C9 contains a valid date format
```

So to pass it to `CurrentMonth` variable, simply assign it using `=` sign:

```
CurrentMonth = MonthName(Month(SetupSheet.Range("C9")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase 'm' is minute. Uppercase 'M' is for month.